# Поменять последовательность полей объекта

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста!
Необходимо поменять последовательность полей объекта на заданную.
Имеется объект:

```
const types = [
    {female: 100, male: 200, children: 150},
    {female: 100, male: 200, children: 150}
];
```

Он приходит с бекенда. Необходимо изменить последовательность на фронте на `male, children, female` соответственно . 
До этого с таким не сталкивался, перпробовал несколько способов, но безуспешно. Буду крайне благодарен за любую помощь. Пример кода вывода полей объекта:

```
{types && (
  <ul>_.map(Object.keys(types), key => (
    <li key={_.uniqueId(`${key}`)}>
      <span>{key, types[key]}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
)}

100 female
200 male
150 children
```

Вывод выглядит вот так.
Необходимо поменять на:

```
200 male
150 children
100 female
```

Comment: Добавь в вопросе пример как именно ты проверяешь последовательность полей

Comment: Самое лучшее решение: хранить список полей, по порядку, и при выводе просто брать значение соответствующего поля

Comment: @Grundy не знаю что вы имеете в виду во втором комменте

Comment: @Grundy вы поставили, что это дубликат. но мне надо не по полю отсортировать, мне надо поменять местами поля вне зависимости от значений полей

Comment: @VladyslavTereshyn как Вы собираетесь использовать "упорядоченность" полей?

Comment: @Igor в каком смысле? мне нужно поменять местами поля объекта для отображения в соответствии с дизайном

Comment: @VladyslavTereshyn, добавил второй источник, показывающий по каким правилам происходит обход объекта.

Comment: @VladyslavTereshyn Где тот код, для которого имеет значение порядок полей?

Comment: @VladyslavTereshyn, в объекте не важен порядок свойств. Он важен при отображении, у тебя нет кода показывающего как именно ты _отображаешь_ объект. Что тебе мешает вручную указать что вот тут выводить такое поле, а за ним такое?

Comment: @Grundy я обновил

Comment: @VladyslavTereshyn, второй дубликат отвечает на вопрос почему у тебя `Object.keys` возвращает ключи именно в таком порядке как возвращает. И, собственно, из этого можно сделать вывод как именно их можно поменять. Самое простое что ты можешь сделать - просто отсортировать эти ключи, так как тебе нужно.

Comment: у вас три известных поля в объекте. Просто сгенерируйте html без цикла. Либо возьмите массив в нужном порядке `['field1', 'field3', 'field2']`  и пройдясь по нему, выведите `obj[field]`. Сама по себе смена порядка полей в объекте не имеет никакого смысла.

Comment: @teran, подозреваю порядок должен был зависеть от значений

Comment: @VladyslavTereshyn, отсортировать можешь например так: `Object.keys(obj).sort((a,b)=>obj[a]-obj[b])`

Comment: @Grundy там вверху написано прямым текстом "вне зависимости от значений полей"

Comment: @teran, да, странно почему я на значениях зациклился :-) тогда все действительно проще - обычный массив полей в нужной порядке, что я уже и писал во втором комментарии. Понял почему, у него в этом порядке значения строго по возрастанию получаются :)

Comment: @Grundy дак я твой 2й коммент и расписал, ибо в третьем автор сказал, что не понял о чем речь (: